# Problemas com mascara jquery e input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu estou tentando colocar um valor no dentro de um **input** que seja mascarado tanto na digitação quanto no valor inserido.

Bom, eu tenho uma lista de imóveis cadastros no banco de dados no qual eu puxo pro front, ok?

E nao entrando em muitas especificações, sempre que insiro um valor no INPUT (Ex.: `100.000,00`) ele vem tranquilo formatado, no entanto quando eu clico em "Salvar" (do meu sistema, irrelevante agora) o valor do input muda pra `100.00`. Segue abaixo o código do front:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="bold label-color-cinza">Preço</label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="" class="form-control input-sm moeda" name="valor" value="<?= $imovel->valor ?>" placeholder="Preço">
</div>
```

Por favor, estou tentando de tudo e sempre dá nisso.
Abaixo o código do mask:

```
$('.moeda').mask('999.999.999,99');
```

Está dentro de um **ready** tranquilo, aqui ta tranquilo.

De novo, meu PROBLEMA É:

- Não consigo fixar o valor de entrada com o valor gravado na input.

Grato a todos que puderem ajudar!!!

EDIT 1: Depois de algumas sugestões de vocês o problema persistiu. A mascara na digitação está ótima. Eu sempre testo usando o valor 100.000,00 e o resultado impresso fica 100,00.

100.000,00 => 100,00
10.000,00 => 10,00
1.000.000,00 => 1,00

Viram que ele ta pegando sempre os dígitos antes do 1º ponto e acrescentando os ",00" [Fim EDIT 1]

Comment: Tente mudar o mask e use ele assim:  $('.moeda').mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true});

Comment: Sinto muito mano, mas o problema persiste... A mascara na digitação está ótima, mas quando eu salvo ele altera o valor, como eu disse acima, eu sempre testo usando 100.000,00 e ao dar o "salvar" o valor muda para 100,00 e cada vez que eu aumento um zero na digitação, ele decrementa 1 zero no numero que fica impresso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o input é tipo text, e possui virgulas, o que o input está retornando é uma string, e pra isso, terá que formatar o value do mesmo transformando em um número:

```js
function formatVal(val){
  let valor = val;
  let valTot = 0;
  return valTot += Number(valor.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));
}

console.log(formatVal('100.000,97'))
```

No let valor ali, no caso, você vai pegar o valor do input. (acho que agora se sabe fazer rs) ai com o número formatado desse jeito, da pra você fazer os cálculos que precisa.

Comment: Amigo, estou tentando adaptar o seu códigos sugestivo a minha necessidade, sendo que eu ainda preciso que o valor de saida seja com '.' e ',' ainda na mascara, ok?

Comment: Sim, @LougansdeMatos, mas pra fazer o calculo você antes tem que tirar os '.' e ','. Depois do calculo feito, você poderá por novamente os mesmos no resultado que foi retornado.

Comment: Entendi e já tentei mano mas mesmo assim não tem dado certo... O que é interessante é que em algumas combinações que fiz ele deu certo da primeira vez, mas a partir da 2ª vez atualizando algum outro dado, o valor quebra e muda... A priore achei que tinha dado certo mas infelizmente ainda não deu rsrs... Continuo buscando ^^

Comment: A tabela que recebe esse valor na DB está como int?

Comment: está como decimal(19,2)

Comment: Não vai dar certo então, porque o valor la do seu input, como tem virgula, etc.. É uma string, daria certo salvar o mesmo como varchar... Ou, tratar o mesmo como eu sugeri, na função acima.

Comment: aaah mano... a gente tenta fazer certo né kkkkk mas se não dá! Valeu cara! Me ajudou... tmj e agradeço por tirar um tempo pra me dar um help :D

Answer (score -2):

Já tentou usar a função `mask` do **Jquery**:

Veja:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $(".real").mask('#.##0,00', { reverse: true });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Como mencionei no comentário ali em cima do Lucas Carvalho, não deu certo... :/